# How to set godot support for rider to 3. x version of Godot

Tags: c#, plugins, godot, jetbrains-rider, rider-plugin

So I recently started using Rider's plugin "Godot Support" for my C# files of a project in the LTS version of Godot (currently 3.5). And while trying to write some code I found that the extension is set for version 4.0 of Godot.

Is there a way to change a parameter for the Godot support plugin so that it support Godot 3.5 instead of 4.0?

I tried searching for parameter for the plugin but couldn't find any and google or the github and rider page didn't have my answers.